# Javascript "for" loop functions sequence

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have some javasctipt code like this https://jsfiddle.net/vhzqvx2e/20/
If you choose 4 files and look into console you will see this

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
4 
Object { name: "FireShot Capture 4", size: 54714, type: "image/png", preview: "data:image/png;base64,"[…] } 
4 -
Object { name: "FireShot Capture 4", size: 54714, type: "image/png", preview: "data:image/png;base64,"[…] }
4 - 
Object { name: "FireShot Capture 4", size: 54714, type: "image/png", preview: "data:image/png;base64,"[…] } 
4 - 
Object { name: "FireShot Capture 4", size: 54714, type: "image/png", preview: "data:image/png;base64,"[…] }
```

As you can see at fisrt i see full loop  console.log(this.count); and then all my code runs at last loop(picture sizes and names for last picture only). How can i make **reader** and SomeCl.processM(info); run at every loop, not 4 times after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- wrap Filereader object creation and 'load' callback inside a IIFE function with it's own lexical scope

---

```
  (function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    info.preview = e.target.result;
                    console.log(SomeCl.count + " -")
                    SomeCl.processM(info);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
      })(files[i]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfzmm1hc/1

Comment: Hmm, i got the same output in console... 1 2 3 4 and 4 times file info after

Comment: Still dont get it. console.log(this.count); and callback ( SomeCl.processM(info) too) in one loop. So we enter the loop, console.log(this.count) show me 1, then it should run callback, and then go for second loop. But now i just get the same result as mine

Comment: it's asynchronous. JavaScript is a single threaded language, meaning only one task can be executed at a time. the loops goes to the end, passing the i values to the function. and only then calls the functions. then the filereader loads the file and only then calls the callback.

Comment: Got it. Is there any method to do what i want? first loop - wait till Reader make his job and call SomeCl.processM(info); and then back to second loop? As far asi know there is some callback mechanisms, but it looks so complicated for me :c

Comment: Okaaay, im so dumb, this https://jsfiddle.net/bfzmm1hc/1/ works like a charm, thanks  a lot. I just put info{} Inside the closure and count++ inside the onload()!

Comment: great! I'll add your fiddle to the answer. sometimes it's just hard to get it right at first.